# Failed due to a lacking or broken API call inherited from UI Automation in UFT

Tags: automated-tests, desktop-application, hp-uft

I get following error message (after a long wait) in `UFT` when try to set value of an input field in a `Java` based desktop application. I checked in Object Repository and it shows correct field in UI of application.

> Failed due to a lacking or broken API call inherited

Comment: What error message?  From what code?  I think you missed out half of the text you needed to include for anyone to be able to help...

Comment: Can you set it manually? (fied enabled etc)

Comment: @Dave: It appears in a popup window, nothing else is in it.

Comment: @BelaTamasJozsa : Yes, I can give input to that field.

Comment: I still don't see any error message in the question so have no idea what the problem you're having is.

Comment: @Dave : That is error message in popup window after a long wait: `Failed due to a lacking or broken API call inherited`

Comment: Is the error message popup coming from UFT or is it coming from your application?  What action are you taking in UFT to try and set the value of the field prior to the popup?  What are the properties of the field you are editing, does it autocomplete when you start typing into it etc?  I'd love to help you but you are providing virtually no useful information to give me any understanding of the problem itself.

Comment: @Dave : It is coming from UFT. It is a simple password field without autocomplete, but it is in a small popup window inside application. Text field is invisible during recording, I used Spy to capture it.

Comment: So the error popup is definitely generated by UFT and is not generated by your application?  Can you use the OR to highlight the object on the relevant page? Can you edit the question to provide more information, including the properties of the text field as the OR has stored them?

Comment: @Dave: I can highlight it and it looks like this: `UIAWindow("MyApplication").UIAWindow("JavaFX173").UIAEdit("JavaFX174").SetValue "mypassword"`

Path of object: `*:*:*:JavaFX178:JavaFX180:JavaFX175:JavaFX174`